# List two columns on ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Trying to show a list of items. I have items and calibrations. I want show all the data from items + date_cal_expired (select the max date, because one item can have many calibrations) from calibrations.

In the controller

```
@items = Item.includes(:calibrations).where('calibrations.date_cal_expired <= ?' , now)
```

In the index

```
<% @items.each do |item| %>
<tr>
    <td><%= item.den_cont %></td>
    <td><%= item.marca %></td>
    <td><%= item.modelo %></td>
    <td><%= item.nro_serie %></td>
    <td><%= item.genre.genre %></td>
    <td><%= item.state.state %></td>
```

What should I do to show date_cal_expired??
I don't know how to show data from other table
Hope you understand. Tks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to perform single query:

```
Item.select("items.*, c.date_cal_expired AS date_cal_expired")
    .joins("LEFT JOIN calibrations AS c ON c.item_id = item.id 
            WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM calibrations AS j 
                               WHERE c.item_id = j.item.id 
                                 AND t.date_cal_expired < j.date_cal_expired)")
```

Now the `date_cal_expired` is an item's attribute:

```
<% item.date_cal_expired %>
```

Or simple solution:

```
<% item.calibrations.map(&:date_cal_expired).try(:max) %>
```

Comment: The first solution really didn't follow you. Don't understand how to resolve the "item attribute". simple solution work fine. Tks amenzhinsky!

Answer (score 0):

```
item.calibrations.pluck(:date_cal_expired).max
```

Answer (score 0):

You have already showed data from other table by using

```
<td><%= item.genre.genre %></td> // this way you go to table genre and display field genre
```

If you want data from other table you should just put

```
<td>
   <% item.calibrations.each do |calibration| %>
      <%= calibration.field_1 %>
      // ....
      <%= calibration.field_n %>
   <% end %>
</td>
```

Comment: tks Nermin, but it doesn't work like that..I have to use "simple method" from amenzhinsky. It's a different relationship. I have item_id in calibrations. Again many tks for your quickly response.

Answer (score 0):

item.calibrations.max("your value")

Comment: It performs two additional queries each item: get item's calibrations and select max value

Comment: get item's calibrations is not perform with my query.

Comment: includes perform "get item's calibrations"